# Is there a solvable 2-box Sokoban puzzle in which the pushes must be interleaved?

Tags: solvability

Say that a solution to a [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) puzzle with only 2 boxes is **box-isolating** if and only if there are step numbers $m$ and $n$ such that for one of the boxes:

- *All* of its pushes were between step $m$ and step $n$, and:
- The other box was not pushed between step $m$ and step $n$

> Is there a Sokoban puzzle with only 2 boxes such that there is a solution but there is no box-isolating solution?

I do not know the answer to this question.
It is related to [this question I asked on cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41058/sokoban-with-only-k-boxes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yes, here is such a board
>  `#######`
>  `###F###`
>  `#...###`
>  `#.#.AS#`
>  `#.#.B##`
>  `#.##.##`
>  `#....F#`
>  `#######`
>  S is the starting position, A and B are the initial positions of the boxes, and F are the final positions. The A-box has to be touched in the first step and the B-box in the second step. But there is no way to take B to a final position without touching A again.